# Multi branched SQL Query running slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a large SQL query for a report with many optional parameters and 20-30 branches in the WHERE clause. The problem is its running very slow. The execution time varies from 6 secs to 5 mins. If I remove one or two conditions it works in 6 secs but with all conditions it takes over 5 mins. The problem is not with any specific indexes or a condition because if I remove ANY ONE condition from the query it improves. There are about 20 tables in the join and about 100 fields in the output. Problem area of the query looks something like this :

```
        AND Abc_ID IN (SELECT * FROM fnSplit(@Abc_IDs, ','))
        AND Xyx_ID IN (SELECT * FROM fnSplit(@Xyz_Ids, ','))
        AND Aaa_ID IN (SELECT * FROM fnSplit(@Aaa_Ids, ','))
        AND Zzz_ID IN (SELECT * FROM fnSplit(@Zzz_Ids, ','))
```

where fnSplit is a udf. Also note if I remove fnsplit with hardcoded value (1,2,3,4,5) it also improves. But my guess is the issue is to do with the server memory or some configuration rather than in an specific clause in the WHERE. As I said earlier there are 20-30 branches in the WHERE clause and removing any one condition improves the performance (a lot).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please post the entire query and the relevant table structures. Without that, your only going to get speculative answers.

Comment: So we have a bunch of AND statements and slow query performance.  What exactly do you think we can help you with knowing only this much information?  Without being able to reproduce the problem all you will get is opinion and guesses.

Comment: Why don't you do something like:

`AND ID IN (SELECT * FROM YourTable (nolock) WHERE ID IN('ABC','AAA','Xyz','zzz'))`

Comment: An approach I often use in situations like this is to create and populate some temp tables, and then get the final results from these tables.

Comment: If the problem is not blocking trying out NOLOCK will not solve any issues and can cause serious problems with the reliability of the data in the report

Comment: Also, what version of sql server are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

Few initial things / ideas that you could try:

1. Check the "Reason for Early Termination" from the leftmost object in the execution plan. If it is timeout, that could be the reason for a (horribly) bad plan
2. Test if replacing the (SELECT * FROM fnSplit..) with a temp. tables would help the optimizer to understand the cardinality better
3. Look at "statistics io", the execution plans and plan cache what is consuming the most I/O and CPU, that might help to understand where the problem is
4. Change the whole thing to be a dynamic SQL
5. Include the execution plan, statistics io and table & indexing structure etc into the question for further analysis

Bonus idea: Compare your split function to [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), maybe that would be better.